# 'IndexError: list index out of range' with Keras TimeDistributed Conv2D

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN-LSTM model. My dataset is made by a bunch of single-channel images of size `(n_spot, n_meas) = (100,102)`. In this small instance, I have got just `n_sim = 20` images so that:

```
print(X_train.shape) -> (12, 100, 102, 1)
print(X_val.shape)   -> (4, 100, 102, 1)
print(X_test.shape)  -> (4, 100, 102, 1)
print(y_train.shape) -> (12, 200)
print(y_val.shape)   -> (4, 200)
print(y_test.shape)  -> (4,200)
```

My code is the following:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()

# add model layers
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size=[3,3], padding = 'same',
                 activation='relu', input_shape=(None,n_spot,n_meas,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(2*n_spot, activation = 'linear'))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

`model.summary()` returns the following error:

```
'This model has not yet been built. '

ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling build() or calling fit() with some data. Or specify input_shape or batch_input_shape in the first layer for automatic build.
```

while I get this one whenever I try to train my model with

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=30)

Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-1109305aff30>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/nle5266/Documents/positioning/reduced_data.py', wdir='C:/Users/nle5266/Documents/positioning')

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/nle5266/Documents/positioning/reduced_data.py", line 338, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=30, callbacks=[tensorboard])

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 677, in _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(x)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 589, in _set_inputs
    self.build(input_shape=(None,) + inputs.shape[1:])

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 221, in build
    x = layer(x)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py", line 248, in call
    y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 171, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3650, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 779, in convolution
    data_format=data_format)

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 828, in __init__
    input_channels_dim = input_shape[num_spatial_dims + 1]

  File "C:\Users\nle5266\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 616, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Googling around, I realized that this kind of problem is usually due to the input shape of the time distributed conv2D layer which should a 4-tuple. I tried with `(None,n_spot,n_meas,1)` with no success.

I'm using keras 2.2.4 with tensorflow 1.12.0. I tried to upgrade tensorflow to the last nightly but it didn't solve the problem.